# SweetAlert2 - How to change title and text color?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I would like to change title and text color in SweetAlert2.

My alerte :

```
Swal.fire({
  icon: 'warning',
  title: 'Attention...',
  text: 'Change color of this text',
  background: '#1e2122',
  confirmButtonColor: '#ff6600',
  confirmButtonText: 'OK',
  iconColor: '#ff6600',
})
```

I have seen this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68639095/how-do-i-change-text-color-in-sweetalert2) but not work for me.

it is necessary to use customClass ?

Could you help me please ? :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `customClass` in the SWAL configuration to give a custom class name to the title or the container and provide the text color in that class.

[SWAL customClass Configuration](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#customClass)

Your configuration when you invoke SWAL should contain the customClass key with value like

```
customClass: {
    title: 'custom-title-class',
  }
```

On your root CSS file

```
.custom-title-class {
  color: green;
}
```

Similarly other styles can also be overridden using their respective entries.

Comment: thanks Dan !

but I don't understand well how use custom CSS class ?

I put CSS code directly inside '...' ?

`customClass: {
  title: 'put css here ?',
}`

Thank you

Comment: Big thanks Dan ! all work fine with your explanations :)

Comment: Happy to help @Maxime !

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use "swall-text" class and give it whatever styling you like.

```
 .swall-text{
     color: red;
  }
```

here are the docs not only text, but we can customize everything on the popup modal https://sweetalert.js.org/docs/#theming